# Create formattable text box on website using javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text

I'm trying to make a website where my friends and I can colaboratively write a story. My first problem is figuring out how to create a text box on the website where a user can just write, with with the ability to do some basic formatting, such as tabs and italics. I'm having trouble finding information on how best to create and save that kind of text. I'm using Javascript and React to create this website, and probably a NoSQL database to hold the various entries. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use something like https://editorjs.io/ . or even https://ckeditor.com/ . look through their documentation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using a pre-existing library for a simple [WHYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor such as [Draft.js](https://draftjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) (has react support and maintained by facebook) . Note with any library you pick you will need be careful with how you are storing and rendering user input, don't want to open yourself up to any XSS attacks. If you want to roll your own for the fun of it then you will need to store state I'd look into the object draft.js stores to handle this

Another issue you are going to run into is the collaboration part. You will need some kind of procedure for handling this. Google docs uses this [Operational Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation). You'll also probably want to look into websockets for handling all this realtime.